# Lower and upper bound of the sum of a series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

Let $S$ be the sum of the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {1}{n\ln (n)^2}$. We show that  $\displaystyle\int_{n=2}^{c} \frac {1}{x\ln (x)^2}dx=\frac{1}{\ln2}-\frac{1}{\ln c}$ so the series is convergent.
 Now we want a lower and an upper bound for $S$. We know that 
$$S_n+\int_{n+1}^{\infty}\frac {1}{x\ln (x)^2}dx \le S \le S_n+\int_{n}^{\infty}\frac {1}{x\ln (x)^2}dx$$ 
My question is how to find the value of $n$ that gives the lowest $S_n+\int_{n}^{\infty}\frac {1}{x\ln (x)^2}dx$ and the biggest $S_n+\int_{n+1}^{\infty}\frac {1}{x\ln (x)^2}dx$

Thank you for your help ?

Comment: The lower bound is strictly increasing, and the upper bound strictly decreasing. So the larger you choose $n$, the tighter your bounds become.